# ServiceWorker fails to load google fonts with CSP exception on refresh

Tags: http-headers, service-worker, content-security-policy, workbox, angular-service-worker

I set the CSP to allow to connect to google font service as below. On first time load everything works fine (I doubt that SW caching anything) but when I refresh the page I see the error inspite of `connect-src` explicitly added google font url.

CSP added to `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="
                default-src 'self' https: fonts.googleapis.com;
                font-src 'self' https: fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com data:;
                style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https: fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com data:;
                child-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com;
                connect-src 'self' https: fonts.googleapis.com;
                object-src 'none';">
```

ngsw-config:

```
     "assetGroups": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "installMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/index.html",
                    "/manifest.webmanifest",
                    "/*.css",
                    "/*.js"
                ],
                "urls": [
                    "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**",
                    "https://fonts.gstatic.com/**"
                ]
            }
        }
```

ERROR:

[image]

Comment: If any of you face similar issue read: https://qubyte.codes/blog/content-security-policy-and-service-workers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have add CSP to wrong `index.html`, not one from angular config.

In you CSP shown `default-src 'self' https: fonts.googleapis.com;...connect-src 'self' https: fonts.googleapis.com;` but according to console warns the violation occurs for `default-src 'self';` and it's used as fallback because of absent *connect-src* directive.

Comment: I added to the current `index.html`, see the link to why the CSP was failing in SW. We should set CSP headers to the SW.js when load from server.

Answer (score 0):

Just to save people some time I'm copying reasoning from the Qubyte Codes blog post.

- When you use PWA (ServiceWorker) then some rules like `image-src`, `font-src` are *not* the *only* ones used to check requests.
- Requests from a ServiceWorker are checked with `connect-src` violations (which fallbacks to `default-src`).
- If you omit `default-src` and `connect-src` in CSP then your PWA should just work.
- You can also set `connect-src: *` (note that `*` only includes normal URLs and not data: and file:, so YMMV, but * should be fine most of the times).
- Initial img request and response from the ServiceWorker will still check rules like `image-src`, `font-src`.

You might want to see a hierarchy of all CSP rules here: [CSP rules hierarchy (png)](https://github.com/Eccenux/CSP-policy/blob/main/CSP-hierarchy.png).

Remember that `connect-src` applies to a bunch of other things (not only PWA). So be careful if you want to add more specific URLs to it. See: [MDN: CSP connect-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src).

The blog post:
https://qubyte.codes/blog/content-security-policy-and-service-workers